# Scala - Passing Class of derived type in place of Class of supertype

Tags: scala

So, I have the following use case.

There is a class called SinglePredictionTester with the following implementaion.

```
class SinglePredictorTester[T <: Class[SurvivalPredictor]](predictorClass: T,
                                                            dataSplitter: DataSplitter,
                                                            titanic: DataFrame) extends PredictionTester {

  import titanic.sqlContext.implicits._

  override def test: Map[SurvivalPredictor, Double] = ???

}
```

The idea is for this class is to take a subclass of SurvivalPredictor class, instantiate it inside and execute some methods to test it's accuracy.

SurvivalPredictor has many implementations.

I plan to call the SinglePredictionTester like this:

```
  val test: Map[SurvivalPredictor, Double] = new SinglePredictorTester(classOf[SexBasedPredictor],
    new DataSplitter {},
    new DataFrameLoader {}.load(getPathForResource("train.csv"),
      sqlContext)).test
```

However this doesn't compile and gives me following error:

```
Error:(13, 46) inferred type arguments [Class[com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.implementations.SexBasedPredictor]] do not conform to class SinglePredictorTester's type parameter bounds [T <: Class[com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.SurvivalPredictor]]
  val test: Map[SurvivalPredictor, Double] = new SinglePredictorTester(classOf[SexBasedPredictor],
                                             ^
```

I'm unable to figure out how to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Class` is not covariant in its generic type parameter. However, you can solve the problem by specifying `T <: SurvivalPredictor`.

```scala
class SinglePredictorTester[T <: SurvivalPredictor](
    predictorClass: Class[T],
    dataSplitter: DataSplitter,
    titanic: DataFrame) extends PredictionTester {

  import titanic.sqlContext.implicits._

  override def test: Map[SurvivalPredictor, Double] = ???
}
```

Comment: What are the reasons for not making Class as non covariant in its generic type parameter? And yea thanks - this syntax works like a charm :)

Comment: The reason is that `Class` is a Java class which does not support covariance.

Comment: @TillRohrmann This doesn't apply to `ClassTag` and `TypeTag`, but they are still invariant.

Comment: @DhruvKapur In addition to the reason given by @TillRohrman, because it shouldn't be. For example, there is just one `Class[Object]`: `classOf[Object]`. If `Class` were covariant, there would be many. So if you had something of type `Class[Object]`, you wouldn't know what class this actually is. You also couldn't usefully write something like `Class[T >: String]`.