# Scala - Passing a Seq/Map of derived class's class in place of base class's class

Tags: scala

This is a follow up question on my previous question:
[Scala - Passing Class of derived type in place of Class of supertype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786581/scala-passing-class-of-derived-type-in-place-of-class-of-supertype)

Following is my use case:
I have a class called `MultiplePredictionTester` with the following implementation...

```
class MultiplePredictionTester[T <: SurvivalPredictor](predictorClasses: Seq[Class[T]],
                                                       restOfConstructorParams: Map[Class[T], Seq[Object]],
                                                       dataSplitter: DataSplitter,
                                                       titanic: DataFrame) extends PredictionTester {

  import titanic.sqlContext.implicits._

  override def test: Map[SurvivalPredictor, Double] = ???
}
```

The idea is to be able to take a sequence of classes derived from `SurvivalPredictor` and instantiate them inside, using a constructor where first argument is fetched from `DataSplitter` while the rest of the arguments come from the `Map[Class[T], Seq[Object]]`

I plan to invoke this class as:

```
object MultiQuickRunner extends App with ResourceGetter {
  val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TitanicSurvivalPredictor").setMaster("local[4]")
  val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
  val sqlContext: SQLContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val test: Map[SurvivalPredictor, Double] =
    new MultiplePredictionTester(Seq(classOf[SexBasedPredictor], classOf[TotallyRandomPredictor]),
      Map[Class[SurvivalPredictor],Seq[Object]](),
      new DataSplitter {},
      new DataFrameLoader {}.load(getPathForResource("train.csv"),
        sqlContext)).test
  test.foreach { case (survivalPredictorInstance, accuracy) =>
    println("Accuracy for " + survivalPredictorInstance.getClass.getName + " is " + accuracy)
  }
}
```

However trying to compile something like that throws me the exception:

```
Error:(27, 5) no type parameters for constructor MultiplePredictionTester: (predictorClasses: Seq[Class[T]], restOfConstructorParams: Map[Class[T],Seq[Object]], dataSplitter: com.dhruvk.kaggle.DataSplitter, titanic: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictiontesters.implementations.MultiplePredictionTester[T] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Seq[Class[_ >: com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.implementations.TotallyRandomPredictor with com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.implementations.SexBasedPredictor <: com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.SurvivalPredictor]], scala.collection.immutable.Map[Class[com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.SurvivalPredictor],Seq[Object]], com.dhruvk.kaggle.DataSplitter, org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Seq[Class[_ >: com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.implementations.TotallyRandomPredictor with com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.implementations.SexBasedPredictor <: com.dhruvk.kaggle.predictors.SurvivalPredictor]]
 required: Seq[Class[?T]]
    new MultiplePredictionTester(Seq(classOf[SexBasedPredictor], classOf[TotallyRandomPredictor]),
    ^
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.Class` is invariant. During class declaration you are telling compiler that it is some T which has a upper bound such that `T <: SurvivalPredictor`. But when initializing you are saying T could `SexBasedPredictor, TotallyRandomPredictor or SurvivalPredictor`. This is not possible.

Consider

```
class A
class B extends A

class Test[T <: A](x: Seq[Class[T]], m: Map[Class[T], Seq[T]])
```

Here I have a class Test with type parameter T with upper bound A. Now I can initialize Test with

```
new Test(Seq(classOf[A], classOf[A]), Map(classOf[A] -> Seq(new B)))
```

As `java.lang.Class` is invariant, once I state `T` as `A`. I cant change it. If I change to `B`, compiler will yell at me. On the other hand as `Seq` is covariant I can say `new B` there.

Answer (score 1):

As [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786581/scala-passing-class-of-derived-type-in-place-of-class-of-supertype#comment55373200_33786888) to Till Rohrman's answer to the linked question mentions, there is just one `Class[T]` for any specific class or trait `T`: `classOf[T]`. So your `predictorClasses` can have length at most 1, and `restOfConstructorParams` can have size of most one. This is not what you want. The correct signature would use [existential types](http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2012/09/03/existential-types):

```
class MultiplePredictionTester(predictorClasses: Seq[Class[_ <: SurvivalPredictor]],
                               ...
```

`Class[_ <: SurvivalPredictor]` is short for `Class[T <: SurvivalPredictor] forSome { type T }` and is the common type for all `Class` objects of subtypes of `SurvivalPredictor`.

It isn't clear what you want to use `restOfConstructorParams` for, but the type you gave is also wrong. It might be `Seq[Any]`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to existential types. However given this, why will one ever use generic types? And probably this is for some other thread. Also, the idea is to dynamically create the instance of class where first parameter is known (will always be training data) however the rest of the params will be sent by the user (which for now is Object, or Any)